# How to queue several functions set by setTimeout with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, task-queue

I have a workflow on JS, which should run several set by setTimeout functions one by one. How this could be done with JS/jQuery, preferably in some easy and beautiful way?

It looks like this

```
function recursiveOne(arg1){
  if (allRight) return;

  doSomething();
  andAnotherOne();
  setTimeout(function(){recursiveOne(arg1)}, 3000);
}

function coreFunction(){
  recursiveOne(arg1);
  recursiveTwo(arg2);
  recursiveThree(arg3);
}
```

where recursiveTwo should start only when recursiveOne already done its last iteration.

The bad part is all functions work through setTimeout because I need to wait reaction from backend, and couldn't receive it directly - only by HTML source.

Possible solutions, that I could see:

- next function callback passed right in the previous function. Not too cool.
- jQuery deffered object, which isn't so beatiful too, but a bit better. The downside is I still should rise additional deffered request in each function I want to use this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a callback or invoke `coreFunction` directly. Below you can find a way to do it using array of functions.

```
function recursiveOne(arg1){
   if(arg1 < 5){
      arg1++;
      setTimeout(function(){recursiveOne(arg1);}, 500);
   }else{
      console.log("func1 complete");
      coreFunction();
   }
}

function recursiveTwo(arg1){
   if(arg1 < 10){
      arg1++;
      setTimeout(function(){recursiveTwo(arg1);}, 500);
   }else{
      console.log("func2 complete");
      coreFunction();
   }
}

function recursiveThree(arg1){
    if(arg1 < 20){
      arg1++;
      setTimeout(function(){recursiveThree(arg1);}, 500);
   }else{
      console.log("func3 complete");
      coreFunction();
   }
} 

var funcSet = [recursiveOne, recursiveTwo, recursiveThree];
var funcArgs = [[1], [5], [10]];

function coreFunction(){
   if(funcSet.length){
       var func = funcSet.shift();
       func.apply(window, funcArgs.shift())
   }
}
coreFunction();
```

Comment: Wow! Great idea, I would try this asap. Thank you!

Comment: This is quiet an ugly solution since all recursive functions are dependent on the name coreFunction. I would really suggest using a callback instead.

Comment: I agree :). Using callback is the perfect solution. Just wanted to show how it can be done without callback.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to send the functions as callbacks

```
function recursiveOne(arg1, callback){
  if (allRight) callback();

  doSomething();
  andAnotherOne();
  setTimeout(function(){recursiveOne(arg1, callback)}, 3000);
}


function coreFunction(){
    recursiveOne(arg1, function(){
        recursiveTwo(arg2)
    });

}
```

**(Side note)** I remember this project helped me alot when doing async stuff:

https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: one small thing, setTimeout(function(){recursiveOne(arg1, callback)}, 3000); then. I mention this in solutions, but it is just not beautiful in my eyes :( And yes, it could become even more ugly on 10-20 subsequent functions.

Comment: Thanks. Feels like you could do this a bit sexier using setInterval.